# Can't enable RequestRateLimiter filter in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to enable RequestRateLimiter in Spring Cloud Gateway. I havr configured other filters, even a custom one, but when I add this to one of my routes:

```
 filters:
    - StripPrefix=1
    - name: RequestRateLimiter
      args:
        redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
        redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 3
```

Spring Boot version:
2.1.6.RELEASE
Spring Cloud version:
Greenwich.SR2

Application code is very basic. Just has a OAuth filter in another class which I have disabled to make sure it won't be the cause of the issue:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.skios.ms.gateway" })
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public static Map<String, String> versions;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(GatewayApplication.class);
        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active") && !System.getenv().containsKey("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE"))
            app.setAdditionalProfiles("local");
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        logger.info("Loaded profile: {}", Arrays.toString(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration(RoutePredicateHandlerMapping routePredicateHandlerMapping) {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.DELETE, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.PATCH).forEach(m -> corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod(m));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        routePredicateHandlerMapping.setCorsConfigurations(new HashMap<String, CorsConfiguration>() {
            {
                put("/**", corsConfiguration);
            }
        });

        return corsConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.csrf().disable().build();
    }
}
```

I get this exception (Of course, if I remove the RequestRateLimiter filter and I just leave the StripPrefix entry, everything works ok. I have stripped down the code of the exception):

```
    2019-07-07 20:46:14.514 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [af6d0b2b] Error [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] for HTTP GET "/orion/v2/entities", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (403 FORBIDDEN)
    2019-07-07 20:46:14.525 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xaf6d0b2b, L:/172.30.41.45:8080 - R:/10.135.138.40:54598] Error starting response. Replying error status

    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
        at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.set(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.SetResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.lambda$null$0(SetResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.java:32) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.call(MonoRunnable.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.call(MonoRunnable.java:32) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallableOnAssembly.call(MonoCallableOnAssembly.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:135) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3848) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDoFinallyFuseable.subscribe(MonoDoFinallyFuseable.java:48) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3848) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
[..]
reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3848) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:226) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:442) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:91) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:161) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) ~[netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:796) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:432) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:333) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen] :
        reactor.core.publisher.Mono.then(Mono.java:4078)
        org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.SetResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.lambda$apply$1(SetResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.java:31)
    Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
        |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.SetResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.lambda$apply$1(SetResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.java:31)
        |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:113)
        |_  Mono.doOnSuccessOrError ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter.filter(GatewayMetricsFilter.java:60)

[...]

org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.apply(ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.java:66)
        |_  Mono.doOnSuccess ⇢ org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.apply(ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter.java:67)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information as to which versions you use (Spring Boot & Spring Cloud) or provide a sample application?

Comment: thanks @TYsewyn I added the version, Application and a more detailed stack trace.

Comment: BTW, I had to add http.csrf().disable().build(); to the SecurityWebFilterChain to disable CSRF as I was getting 403 in POST operations. Maybe it has to do with my problem as I also see a 403 error in the stack trace. The weird thing is that if I disable the RequestRateLimiter filter everything works perfect (I've tried GET, POST, PATCH, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what your problem is.
Did you configure a key resolver? If not, that filter will return 403 by default in case there isn't any. Add `denyEmptyKey: false` to your filter args to allow traffic.
You can also configure a key resolver in your Java config. In case you have multiple you can reference the beans in your `application.yml` file. For more info, see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_redis_ratelimiter

Since I don't have access to a sample app it's rather guess work on my side.
I created a small app that runs locally with only those 2 filters without a problem.

I used the key resolver from the documentation.

```
@Bean
KeyResolver userKeyResolver() {
    return exchange -> Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst("user"));
}
```

Together with following application config:

```
spring.cloud.gateway:
  routes:
    - id: test
      uri: https://google.com
      predicates:
        - Path=/test/**
      filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
        - name: RequestRateLimiter
          args:
            redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 2
            redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 3
```

So if I visit http://localhost:8080/test?user=tysewyn 5 consecutive times (using eg. Postman) the last 2 would return `429 - Too Many Requests`

On a sidenote: that currently doesn't explain why you get this stacktrace though.

Comment: Hi, I mark the question as valid as this was really the problem. I had not defined  the key resolver. Doc should make more clear that defining a key resolver in the configuration is mandatory.

Comment: Now I am facing a minor problem. When a request is rejected client gets the correct code but server logs a huge stacktrace similar to the one I added in my question above. I wonder how I can just have the log include a "rejected an entry from IP..." or similar.

Comment: Can you share a sample application which produces this stacktrace? I would love to see that appear in my console log as I don't see this happening in my test setup.